# Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell audio duration not getting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, audio

I have a strange problem.I am using `Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell` to calculate duration of mp3 file during file uploading process.I am able to read duration when i am running application on my local machine.But i am not getting the duration on server.
My serevr is `windown server 2012, 64-bit`

following is my code sample

```
ShellFile so = ShellFile.FromFilePath(Server.MapPath("/Uploads/Track/"+ filename));
return so.Properties.System.Media.Duration.Value.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by re implementing the functionality with TagLib c# library